# Calculate values from two dataframes in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to group and sum for a PySpark (2.4) Dataframe but can't only get values one by one.

I've the following dataframe :

```
data.groupBy("card_scheme", "failed").count().show()

+----------------+------+------+
|     card_Scheme|failed| count|
+----------------+------+------+
|             jcb| false|     4|
|american express| false| 22084|
|            AMEX| false|     4|
|      mastercard|  true|  1122|
|            visa|  true|  1975|
|            visa| false|126372|
|              CB| false|     6|
|        discover| false|  2219|
|         maestro| false|     2|
|            VISA| false|    13|
|      mastercard| false| 40856|
|      MASTERCARD| false|     9|
+----------------+------+------+
```

I'm trying to calculate the formula `X = false / (false + true)` for each card_scheme and still get one dataframe in the end.

I'm expecting something like:

```
| card_scheme | X |
|-------------|---|
| jcb         | 1 |
| ....        | . |
| visa        | 0.9846| (which is 126372 / (126372 + 1975)        
| ...         | . |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Creating the dataset***

```
myValues = [('jcb',False,4),('american express', False, 22084),('AMEX',False,4),('mastercard',True,1122),('visa',True,1975),('visa',False,126372),('CB',False,6),('discover',False,2219),('maestro',False,2),('VISA',False,13),('mastercard',False,40856),('MASTERCARD',False,9)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['card_Scheme','failed','count'])
df.show()
+----------------+------+------+
|     card_Scheme|failed| count|
+----------------+------+------+
|             jcb| false|     4|
|american express| false| 22084|
|            AMEX| false|     4|
|      mastercard|  true|  1122|
|            visa|  true|  1975|
|            visa| false|126372|
|              CB| false|     6|
|        discover| false|  2219|
|         maestro| false|     2|
|            VISA| false|    13|
|      mastercard| false| 40856|
|      MASTERCARD| false|     9|
+----------------+------+------+
```

**Method 1:** This method will be slower, as it involves a traspose via `pivot`.

```
df=df.groupBy("card_Scheme").pivot("failed").sum("count")
df=df.withColumn('X',when((col('True').isNotNull()),(col('false')/(col('false')+col('true')))).otherwise(1))
df=df.select('card_Scheme','X')
df.show()
+----------------+------------------+
|     card_Scheme|                 X|
+----------------+------------------+
|            VISA|               1.0|
|             jcb|               1.0|
|      MASTERCARD|               1.0|
|         maestro|               1.0|
|            AMEX|               1.0|
|      mastercard|0.9732717137548239|
|american express|               1.0|
|              CB|               1.0|
|        discover|               1.0|
|            visa|0.9846120283294506|
+----------------+------------------+
```

**Method 2:** Use SQL - you can do so the via `windows` function. This will be a lot faster.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
df = df.groupBy("card_scheme", "failed").agg(sum("count"))\
  .withColumn("X", col("sum(count)")/sum("sum(count)").over(Window.partitionBy(col('card_scheme'))))\
  .where(col('failed')== False).drop('failed','sum(count)')
df.show()

+----------------+------------------+
|     card_scheme|                 X|
+----------------+------------------+
|            VISA|               1.0|
|             jcb|               1.0|
|      MASTERCARD|               1.0|
|         maestro|               1.0|
|            AMEX|               1.0|
|      mastercard|0.9732717137548239|
|american express|               1.0|
|              CB|               1.0|
|        discover|               1.0|
|            visa|0.9846120283294506|
+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Really helpful ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

First split root dataframe into two dataframes:

```
df_true = data.filter(data.failed == True).alias("df1")
df_false =data.filter(data.failed == False).alias("df2")
```

Then doing full outer join we can get final result:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when
df_result = df_true.join(df_false,df_true.card_scheme == df_false.card_scheme, "outer") \
    .select(when(col("df1.card_scheme").isNotNull(), col("df1.card_scheme")).otherwise(col("df2.card_scheme")).alias("card_scheme") \
            , when(col("df1.failed").isNotNull(), (col("df2.count")/(col("df1.count") + col("df2.count")))).otherwise(1).alias("X"))
```

No need to do `groupby`, just extra two dataframes and joining.

Comment: Your code will work perfectly and will solve the problem at hand. I just have a small remark to make - `joins` are quite costly operation if the data is stored on multiple partitions, as it will involve a shuffle. Where as a `groupBy` may do the grouping on local partitions first and then do the shuffle. So, the number of rows shuffled will be lot less, making it more efficient to work with. Regards,

Comment: Yes. I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

`data.groupBy("card_scheme").pivot("failed").agg(count("card_scheme"))` should work. I am not sure about the `agg(count(any_column))`, but the clue is `pivot` function. In result you'll get two new columns: `false` and `true`. Then you can easily calculate the `x = false / (false + true)`.

Comment: Well, this is really close from what I want but this sometimes gives me "null" values

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to do a second groupby:

```
val grouped_df = data.groupBy("card_scheme", "failed").count() // your dataframe
val with_countFalse = grouped_df.withColumn("countfalse", when($"failed" === "false", $"count").otherwise(lit(0)))
with_countFalse.groupBy("card_scheme").agg(when($"failed" === "false", $"count").otherwise(lit(0)))) / sum($"count")).show()
```

The idea is that you can create a second column which has the failed in the failed=false and 0 otherwise. This means that the sum of the count column gives you false + true while the sum of the countfalse gives just the false. Then simply do a second groupby

Note: Some of the other answers use pivot. I believe the pivot solution would be slower (it does more), however, if you do choose to use it, add the specific values to the pivot call, i.e. pivot("failed", ["true", "false"]) to improve performance, otherwise spark would have to do a two path (the first to find the values)

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
from pyspark.sql.functions import col    
data = data.groupby("card_scheme", "failed").count()
```

Create 2 new dataframes:

```
a = data.filter(col("failed") == "false").groupby("card_scheme").agg(func.sum("count").alias("num"))
b = data.groupby("card_scheme").agg(func.sum("count").alias("den"))
```

Join both the dataframes:

```
c = a.join(b, a.card_scheme == b.card_scheme).drop(b.card_scheme)
```

Divide one column with another:

```
c.withColumn('X', c.num/c.den)
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! Didn't need to change anything :)